PHP absolute path to include file fails
I have located PHP include files for a bunch of systems above the web-root directory, using absolute paths, for many years.  Suddenly it is failing on a new system running Rocky Linux 9, PHP Version 8.3.12,  and Apache version 2.4.57.
Code:
$path = "/home/user/scripts"; // absolute path
set_include_path($path);
require_once("functions.php");

Results:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required
'/home/user/scripts/functions.php' (include_path='/home/user/scripts')
in /home/user/www/index.php:5  Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
/home/user/www/index.php on line 5

require_once("/home/user/scripts/functions.php");  // this also fails with same error

It makes no sense to me.  The scripts directory permissions and file permissions are 755. File name is correct.
Any idea what could be wrong?

When I try this locally, before the fatal error I also see warning which includes a description such as "Failed to open stream: Permission denied" or "Failed to open stream: No such file or directory" that makes it more obvious. Are you seeing that?

No, the entire error message is:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/user/scripts/functions.php'

Can you check your error levels and make sure they are set at -1 or E_ALL?

error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

Make sure the PHP process is allowed to access the file. Usually the user/group is www-data depending on the webserver.

I think it is the Apache user that actually needs permission and the file and directory all have read and executable rights for owner/group/other.     Don't have any user or group called www-data.

@phper, I'm not certain why you aren't seeing the warnings. Here's an example of what they should look like: https://3v4l.org/hgjdA#v8.3.12

After allowing warnings there is an additional message:
Warning: require_once(/home/user/scripts/functions.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/user/www/testinclude.php
However, I have no idea which file or directory has the wrong permissions and as far as I know file and directory permissions of 755 should allow access.

Is it possible that SELinux is causing the problem? https://serverfault.com/a/1022398/75021

"directory permissions of 755 should allow access" - presumably you are talking about the scripts dir, but how about /home/user?  A user needs x on the parent dir to see a child dir.

Thank you so much Chris Haas --  Selinux was the issue.   These two commands resolved the problem:
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/user/scripts
sudo restorecon -RF /home/user/scripts
I want to use Selinux but it throws wrenches at me and somehow it still doesn't occur to me to investigate.

Thank you so much Chris Haas -- Selinux was the issue. These two commands resolved the problem:
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/user/scripts 
sudo restorecon -RF /home/user/scripts

